# Image formation by a convex lens without a screen

Tags: optics, lenses

The real image of an object placed between f and 2f from a convex lens can be seen on a screen placed at the image location. If the screen is removed, would the image be still perceived? Is the image suspended in air at a certain point where the rays from the object is converging?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get in line with the light travelling through the lens at a location beyond the real image point and look back toward the lens, you can see the image "floating" in the air.  If you get far off-axis, you won't see it. The light from the image must travel (somehow) to your eyes.  It takes some practice to get your eyes to focus on the image rather that the lens or other surroundings, but it can be done.  Mirrors work very nicely, too, to let you see images from off-axis positions.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the real image is still located at the same point in space, like an object. But each point on this "object" will only radiate light into a cone with the same f number as the lens (at the focal distance of the image) so if your eye is not in those cones you would not perceive it. You can also use another lens like a magnifier to look at the image as if it were a real object, this is basically what's happening in simple telescope and microscope designs.